# Creating state children before switching to state

Tags: apache-flex, flex4

In my view I have a welcome screen:

```
<component:WelcomeScreen
    includeIn="welcome"
    />
```

Which is a pretty small component and I have panelContainer:

```
<component:PanelContainer
    id="panelView"
    includeIn="panels"
    >

    <manyChildren />

</component:PanelContainer>
```

Whilst the user is reading the warm and fuzzy welcome note in the welcome state I want to be creating the big expensive panels state so taht when we switch there is no delay.

Before the panels state is set panelView is null but I presume there must be an IDefferredInstance floating around somewhere that I can use to kick off the creation of the view. How can I get hold of it?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can set the creationPolicy of your ViewStack to 'all' then all the containers will be created instantly.

Comment: This is not a view stack. This is using the new states functionality in Flex 4.